# odoo using two filters at the same time

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8

I have a problem with using two or more filters at the same time.

For example if I enable two filters "Today" and "Tomorrow" then the SQL query recognizes it as "Today OR Tomorrow" sentence.

Is there a way to make it as `Today AND Tomorrow` sentence so the SQL query would consider both? I do not want to make a third filter `Today and Tomorrow`

My XML code is here:

```
<record id="view_klient_tellimus" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">picking.klient.tellimus.filter</field>
    <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string="Search Picking">
            <filter name="today" string="Today" domain="[('route_time','&lt;=', datetime.datetime.combine(context_today(), datetime.time(23,59,59))), ('route_time','&gt;=', datetime.datetime.combine(context_today(), datetime.time(0,0,0)))]"/>
            <filter name="tomorrow" string="Tomorrow" domain="[('route_time','&lt;=', datetime.datetime.combine(context_today()+datetime.timedelta(days=1), datetime.time(23,59,59))), ('route_time','&gt;=', datetime.datetime.combine(context_today()+datetime.timedelta(days=1), datetime.time(0,0,0)))]"/>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you need to use `separator`s for `AND` filters.

So try this:

```xml
<record id="view_klient_tellimus" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">picking.klient.tellimus.filter</field>
    <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string="Search Picking">
            <filter name="today" string="Today" domain="[('route_time','&lt;=', datetime.datetime.combine(context_today(), datetime.time(23,59,59))), ('route_time','&gt;=', datetime.datetime.combine(context_today(), datetime.time(0,0,0)))]"/>
            <separator />
            <filter name="tomorrow" string="Tomorrow" domain="[('route_time','&lt;=', datetime.datetime.combine(context_today()+datetime.timedelta(days=1), datetime.time(23,59,59))), ('route_time','&gt;=', datetime.datetime.combine(context_today()+datetime.timedelta(days=1), datetime.time(0,0,0)))]"/>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Do you know any web pages where i can read that kind of documentation?

Comment: There are some blogs, but i prefer the [official Odoo doc](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/), stack overflow and the code itself. The [OCA](https://github.com/OCA) has some very good modules, from which you can learn alot, too.